# Complexity of a dynamic programming versus memoization in this case?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Here's a little exercise i'm working on about dynamic programming. I have the following function :

[image]

I have to program this function with two approaches (top-down with memoization and bottom-up).

Here's what I currently do for bottom up:

```
    public static int functionBottomUp (int n){
            int [] array = new int[n+1];
            array[0] = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
                if(i == 1)
                    array[i] = array[i - 1];
                else {
                    for(int p = 0; p < i; p ++)
                        array[i] += array[p];
                }
            }
            return array[n];
   }
```

And for memoization :

```
public static int functionMemoization(int n){
        int[] array = new int[n+1];     
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            array[i] = 0;
        return compute(array, n);
    }

    private static int compute(int[] array, int n){
        int ans = 0;
        if(array[n] > 0)
            return array[n];
        if(n == 0 || n == 1)
            ans = 1;
        else 
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                ans += compute(array, i);
        array[n] = ans;
        return array[n];
    }
```

---

I get correct outputs for both but now i'm struggling myself to calculate the complexities of both.

First the **complexity** of `f(n)` is `2^n` because `f(3)` make `7` calls to `f(0)` and `f(4)` make `15` calls to `f(0)` (I know this is not a formal proof but this is just to give me an idea).

But now i'm stuck for calculating the complexity of both functions.

---

**Bottom-Up :** 
I would say that the complexity is O(n) (because of the `for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)`) but there is this inner loop `for(int p = 0; p < i; p ++)` and I don't know if this modifies the complexity.

**Memoization :** 
Clearly this is a most O(n) because of the first loop which initialize the array. But I don't know how the compute function could modify this complexity.

Could someone clarify this for me ?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that f(n) = 2^(n-1), n >= 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your functions.  Here's the bottom-up DP version:

```
public static int functionBottomUp (int n){
        int [] array = new int[n+1];
        array[0] = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
            if(i == 1)
                array[i] = array[i - 1];
            else {
                for(int p = 0; p < i; p ++)
                    array[i] += array[p];
            }
        }
        return array[n];
}
```

To count up the work that's being done, we can look at how much work is required to complete loop iteration i for some arbitrary i.  Notice that if i = 1, the work done is O(1). Otherwise, the loop runtime is taken up by this part here:

```
for(int p = 0; p < i; p ++)
    array[i] += array[p];
```

The time complexity of this loop is proportional to i. This means that loop iteration i does (more or less) i work.  Therefore, the total work done is (approximately)

> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

So the runtime here is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) rather than O(n) as you conjectured in your question.

Now, let's look at the top-down version:

```
public static int functionMemoization(int n){
    int[] array = new int[n+1];     
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
    return compute(array, n);
}

private static int compute(int[] array, int n){
    int ans = 0;
    if(array[n] > 0)
        return array[n];
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
        ans = 1;
    else 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ans += compute(array, i);
    array[n] = ans;
    return array[n];
}
```

You initially do Θ(n) work to zero out the array, then call `compute` to compute all the values. You're eventually going to fill in all of `array` with values and will do so exactly once per array element, so one way to determine the time complexity is to determine, for each array entry, how much work is required to fill it.  In this case, the work done is determined by this part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ans += compute(array, i);
```

Since you're memoizing values, when determining the work required to evaluate the function on value n, we can pretend each recursive call takes time O(1); the actual work will be accounted for when we sum up across all n.  As before, the work here done is proportional to n. Therefore, since n ranges from 1 to n, the work done is roughly

> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Which again is more work than your estimated O(n).

However, there is a *much* faster way to evaluate this recurrence.  Look at the first few values of f(n):

- f(0) = 1
- f(1) = 1
- f(2) = 2
- f(3) = 4
- f(4) = 8
- f(5) = 16
- ...
- f(n) = 2<sup>n-1</sup>

Therefore, we get that

- f(0) = 1
- f(n) = 2<sup>n-1</sup> if n > 0

Therefore, the following function evaluates `f` time:

```
int f(int n) {
    return n == 0? 1 : 1 << (n - 1);
}
```

Assuming that you're working with fixed-sized integers (say, 32-bit or 64-bit integers), this takes time O(1).  If you're working with arbitrary-precision integers, this will take time Θ(n) because you can't express 2<sup>n-1</sup> without writing out Θ(n) bits, but if we're operating under this assumption the runtimes for the original code would also need to be adjusted to factor in the costs of the additions. For simplicity, I'm going to ignore it or leave it as an exercise to the reader. ^_^

Hope this helps!

Comment: Computing 2^n is Omega(log n) not O(1).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri- I was assuming that we're dealing with fixed-sized integers, which is where I got the O(1) from. But you're absolutely right... if you allow n to be unbounded, the runtime will be larger than that.

Comment: You are somehow right, but as I can see your current function is linear to n (I mean you din't use any special functionality for fixed size model or you should consider original algorithm as O(1)), you can use exponention by squaring to speed it up to O(log n).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Could you explain why `f(int n)` is `Omega(log n)` ? I don't get it

Comment: @user2336315, templatetypedef function right now is Omega(n), because uses n-1 times shifting, but if you use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) you can speed it up to log n. (sure he can explain it much more better than me in his answer by update).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Ok, so it's not `O(1)` ?

Comment: @user2336315 no it's not O(1), as I know templatetypedef, he will update his answer to explain this in more detail (he can do it better than me).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri- It's more accurately Theta(n) time to compute 2^(n-1) because you can't write out 2^(n-1) in fewer than n bits. I've updated the answer to address this, though if this is the case we'd need to repeat the analysis of the original algorithm to factor in the costs of the additions.

Comment: Exponentiation by squaring is not required. Shifts (by any amount) can be explained as iterating over the bit-array once, moving every bit by the shift amount. Much easier explanation - still the same time complexity.

Comment: @templatetypedef, I guess you missed my point, I mean you doing O(n) time shift, this has nothing to do with fixed size RAM model, I mean you assumed that you doing at most 32 bit shift, but may be overflow happens and you need more shifts.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri- Oh, I see what you're saying. My assumption is that we're working with fixed-size variables, so all shifts are O(1). If we're dealing with variable-sized integers, then the time complexity will be greater

Comment: @SaeedAmiri- Fixed-sized shifts are implemented in hardware to take O(1) time, IIRC.

Comment: @templatetypedef, fair enough in real world. but n is not fix ;-)

Comment: @harold, that's not a same time complexity.